# I want to compare system date with my SQL stored database date using query in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i have stored data in SQL.there is a column "date" with 'DateTime' data type. now i want to compare system date with my database date using query. please help friends thanks in advance.

i have tried this code which are shown in its shows the total data of table. i want to show data current date to last 3 month of data of my tabel.(thanks)

What I have tried:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
  con.Open();
  try
  {
    DateTime maxdate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    DateTime mindate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-3);
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from general1 where date<='" + maxdate + "' AND date>='" + mindate + "'" ;
```

Comment: Do not use concatenated inline SQL like that. It is a bad habbit and leads to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Use parameterized SQL. `SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from general1 where date<=@maxdate AND date>=@minDate;` then add params with the date values to your command

Comment: run query and wrtie date logic in stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a control bound to the `SqlDataSource1` component from your sample code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from general1 where date<= current_timestamp AND date>= dateadd(month, -3, current_timestamp)";
}
```

Comment: hi joel Coehoorn thank you so much..its working(thanks again)

Comment: i also play counter strike. i have compeleted all the stages with easy,normal,hard mode..